# HtmlAgilityPack xpath query not working as intended - it should select sub nodes of selected node

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Ok now this first xpath query selects all li nodes with certain id as below

This is working as intented

```
       foreach (var myParticularNode in
 hDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes
("//li[contains(@id,'question')]").EmptyIfNull())
            {
```

Now these returned nodes do have children nodes and those children have other children nodes etc. What i want is make another xpath query to select all hyper link nodes in this particular `myParticularNode`

So i am doing as below

```
 foreach (var myParticularNode in hDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//li[contains(@id,'question')]").EmptyIfNull())
        {
            foreach (var vrNodes in myParticularNode.SelectNodes("//a"))
            {
```

Now this above part is not working as intented. It is not selecting the hyper links ('a') nodes in that particular `myParticularNode` but select from whole document.

This is all about `HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument hDoc`

So to make my question even more clear

Assume i selected a node in whole html document
Now i want to select another node only inside from this selected first node

But it is not working as intended

Comment: Have you tried to give a relative path such as `".//a"`?

Comment: Why not using XPath: `//li[contains(@id,'question')]//a`

Comment: well my question is more specially how to iterate inside selected node. though i found my answer. it was descendants.